# Access to Stream's feed databases

Tags: getstream-io

Stream saves all the activities and follows on their databases in JSON format. However, I find the explorer provided in the dashboard unpractical and I'm wondering if I can access the databases externally, outside of the dashboard to make some integrations with aws services for example. So can I? And if not, is there any workaround so I can manage the databases more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Stream is accessible, to insert and retrieve data, via a REST and realtime APIs, webhooks and Amazon SQS.

There are API Clients and Framework Integrations in [various languages](https://getstream.io/docs/#clients) to help integrate Stream in your application.